# bounding $\sum_{i=1}^m 2^{2^i \cdot k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to put a nicer upper bound for $\sum_{i=1}^m 2^{2^i \cdot k}$ than $2\cdot 2^{2^m\cdot k}$ which is twice the last term of the series. (In fact it seems that $1.5 \cdot 2^{2^m \cdot k}$ works and why shouldn't the constant be even smaller?) Evaluating $\int_{1}^m (2^k)^{2^x}dx$ lead to function $\frac{1}{\log(2)}(Ei(2^{-m}\log2^k)-Ei(1/2\log2^k))$ on Mathematica and I don't know what it means. Any thoughts?

Comment: You could always use that upper bound you know to get a better one, say $$\sum_{i=1}^{m} 2^{2^i k} = 2^{2^m k} + \sum_{i=1}^{m-1} 2^{2^i k} \leq 2^{2^m k} + 2 \cdot 2^{2^{m-1} k}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$Ei(x)$ is the [exponential integral function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html).

Assuming that $k>0$, the terms in the sum are monotonically increasing, so the sum is bounded above by $\int_1^{m+1} (2^k)^{2^x}dx$. Let $u=(2^{k})^{2^x}$. Then $du=k\log(2) u \log(2) \frac{\log(u)}{\log(2^k)} dx=\log(2)u\log(u)dx$. This gives:

$$\frac{1}{\log(2)}\int_{2^k}^M\frac{1}{\log(u)}du,$$

where $M=(2^k)^{m+1}$, and now do one more change of variables $u=e^v$, with $du=e^{v}dv$, so the integral is:

$$\frac{1}{\log(2)}\int_{k}^{log(M)}\frac{e^v}{v}dv=\frac{1}{\log(2)}\left[\mbox{Ei}(k2^{m+1}\log(2))-\mbox{Ei}(2k\log(2))\right],$$

by definition of the exponential integral function, and after a substitution.

Now, $\log(2)$ is positive, and $\mbox{Ei}(x)$ is positive and increasing as $x$ gets larger. You can apply an integration by parts trick, like [the one here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250934/asymptotics-of-exponential-integral), to get a growth rate estimate, which is something like $e^{x}/x$, and in your case $x=k2^{m+1}\log(2)$. Numerically the agreement is excellent for $x>10$